# Curve Smoothening

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I am plotting my data having a time-series line graph from a csv file with the command given below:

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(reshape2)  

meltdf <- melt(AIB,id="Time")

ggplot(meltdf,aes(x=Time,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable),
lwd=10) + geom_line(size=2) + geom_smooth(method="gam", formula =y~s(x), se=FALSE) + geom_point(size=3)
```

I want to do the following things:

1. Change the method of smoothening, want to use the B-Spline curve smoothening.
2. Remove the unsmoothed line, just want to keep smoothed curve.

Please suggest me codes to do the above things.

Comment: Check out `ggalt` package, it contains `geom_xspline`

Comment: Maybe the 4th example in `help('geom_smooth')`.